# SQL QUERY for parent child relationship and Dynamic Compression

Tags: sql, parent-child, mlm

I need help writing a query for a parent-child relationship with dynamic compression.

The table here is

```
member_id   parent_id   fullname    username    product
1           0           Alpha       alpha       1
2           1           A           A           1
3           1           B           B           1
4           1           C           C           1
5           2           A1          A1          0
6           2           A2          A2          0
7           2           A3          A3          4
8           5           A11         A11         5
9           5           A12         A12         5
10          5           A13         A13         0
11          6           A21         A21         5
12          6           A22         A22         5
13          8           a111        a111        5
14          13          a1111       a1111       5
15          14          a11111      a11111      4
16          15          a111111     a111111     4
17          16          a1111111    a1111111    2
18          17          a11111111   a11111111   1
19          3           B1          B1          1
```

After processing this table there will be one field with total_product which will contain the sum of products of their first child.

And if the member doesn't have any product with hum, then the sum of the product will be added to his parent. And even if the parent doesn't have any product, then that sum will be added to his parent, and so on.

Please guide me on this

Comment: Not sure i fully understand.  I'd start with your table joining to your table, alias them as parents and children for example on `from table as parents left join table as children on parents.memberid=children.parentid`  as i said, not sure i fully understand :)

Comment: *"Please guide me on this"* - "please write this for me" (Ask a question about code *you wrote*, and are stuck with at a certain point.)

Comment: From the above table we can get, these details
1. the Member with its parent id, and its total products.
2. the member with its parent id, and its total products, and also the total product from its first child. 

Example alpha has 1 product and his 1st child products will be 3, 

What i am looking for is, if the alpha himself don't have any product then this 3 which is the sum of products of his 1st child, will be added to alpha's parent, and so on